# Cache SQL chunk with R Markdown / Notebook without Knitting in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have a chunk of SQL in my R Markdown / Notebook Document:

````
```{sql output.var = "df"}
SELECT * FROM FakeData
WHERE Date >= '2017-01-01
```
````

It takes literally 5 minutes to run. Is there an easy way to cache the result of the query without Knitting the document or writing the file to a CSV.

I'd perhaps like the cache to live for a couple of hours, or maybe a day (is there a way to adjust this as well?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put `cache=TRUE` in the chunk options and you are working in rStudio, you can select a section of code and run it directly using the green arrows in the upper right of the rMarkdown/knitr console.

`{sql output.var = "df", cache=TRUE}
SELECT * FROM FakeData
WHERE Date >= '2017-01-01`

Also, I tend to run a regular R script in another window with EVERYTHING I am going to use in knitR. I find that I have less issues with package availability and caching if the data is stored in the global environment.

If you do it this way, and run with cache=TRUE you will definitely be able to save the data on the first run and skip the waiting next time around.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the cache argument in the chunk only worked for knitr?

Comment: `cache` should work for any code chunks; if not, it is probably a bug and you should report to https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues

Comment: I missed part of what you were asking. No, in notebooks it does not work the same way with cache=TRUE. But if you run it in a script and keep it in the global environment you should be able to use it in the notebook during development. I just tested it and it works for me from chunk to chunk...

Comment: I believe @sconfluentus is right, and that sql chunks in rnotebooks do not represent the cache chunk argument.