# Unable to run SQL chunk with code and cache options in global environment

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

I am running a large query from a script file (.sql) using a SQL chunk with cache = TRUE to avoid querying the database unnecessarily.

````r
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "...", timeout = 10)
sql_str <- read_file("sql_script.sql")
`` `


```{sql, connection = con, code = sql_str, output.var = "rawdata", cache = TRUE, include = FALSE}
`` `

```{r}
head(rawdata)
`` `
````

This works well with Knitr however the SQL chunk would not run and create the dataframe in the global environment during development, which is annoying. When I try to run the chunk, nothing happens perhaps because the chunk is in fact empty?

In the end, I would like to have the query run and dataframe available in the global environment. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Curious, where is the documentation for those `sql` chunk arguments: *code*, *cache*?

Comment: I find documentation is sparse, I actually found out it was possible with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284274/cache-sql-chunk-with-r-markdown-notebook-without-knitting-in-rstudio

Comment: But what about *code* which I am more interested in? Try passing actual `.sql` file in it.

Comment: See https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-chunk for _code_ option. It basically replaces the chunk contents with `sql_str` which contains the query string.